# Magento 1.9 : Some of Backend Accounts Can Not Login to Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

`**Some of backend accounts cannot login to admin dashboard**` **but some accounts can do**, I checked users accesses level but I do not know what is problem?

After enter **username** and **password** on admin login form, I **redirect to frontend dashboard**.

Comment: Have you check magento log file? Is there any things?

Comment: Yes I checked, but last line error is for 2017-12-03 date and there is not any error about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "*I checked users accesses level*"? Did you check **System->Permissions->Users** select the user that cannot login and than go to the **User Role** and make sure that one of the role is checked.